#  In OCaml, is it possible to define Map in terms of Set?

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I have implemented a representation of sets (balanced search trees) in OCaml.  It's actually a functor `Make` of signature

```
module Make :
  functor (T : ORDERED_TYPE) ->
sig
  type elt = T.t
  type t
  val empty : t
  val cons : elt -> t -> t
  val delete : elt -> t -> t
  val mem : elt -> t -> bool
  val cardinal : t -> int
end
```

where

```
 module type ORDERED_TYPE = sig type t val compare : t -> t -> int end
```

Now I'd like to implement a dictionary like `Map` in the standard library.  It has to have a signature like

```
 module Make: functor (T : ORDERED_TYPE) -> sig
    type key = T.t
    type +'a t
    ...
 end
```

where `t` is the type of dictionaries.

Implementing balanced search trees again is not elegant, so I want to define dictionaries in terms of sets implemented as a functor above.  Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me a map is a (partial) function, which is a set of ordered pairs.  If you define your comparison function correctly I think it can be done.  You might have to add a function to the Set interface to account for the fact that two values can compare equal for purposes of membership but not actually be equal values.  It doesn't seem possible to define the lookup function for the map with the current interface.

Answer (score 4):

As Jeffrey noted, you `Set` interface is not expressive enough to conveniently implement `Map` on top of it. It would be simpler to implement `Set` from `Map`, by defining sets as maps from keys to unit value.

Another possibility, that I would recommend, is to first expose a module of balanced search trees *with no encapsulation*, with the sole purpose of providing an efficient data structure, that is entirely revealed by the interface. You are then free to reuse it for any data structure you like, including `Map` and `Set`, without having to play games to define one in term of the other. This may not be terribly important in this case (defining `Set` from `Map` is reasonable for most purposes), but is a better design in the general case, in my opinion.

In a nutshell: if you want to reuse implementations, then expose "implementation modules", and define your "interface modules" on top of them.

Comment: The problem is that the statement of the homework seems to require me to define Map in terms of Set in very vague words.  BTW, if I try to pass a structure to Set, I have to define type t, but how can I do that?  I want t to be polymorphic type.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, there are at least two reasons why you cannot implement the requested map functor on top of the given set:

1. The set signature provides no way to *find* an "equal" element in a given set.
2. And even if it did, you could not store values in there polymorphically, as the type `'a map` seems to require.

Are you sure that the task requires you to implement maps *on top of* sets? Maybe you are just supposed to implement them *like* sets?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there actually IS an **equal** operator in there -- the **compare** function from the ordered type.

So define your own module for a key/value type that only takes into comparison the key-part:

```
module Keyvalue = struct
   type t = ('a * 'b)
   let compare x y = Pervasives.compare (fst x) (fst y)
end
```

and you are done. The problem now is, that your *Set* does not allow you to get its values; there is no *get* nor a *fold* function -- which imho is really limiting for such a data structure.
If you are allowed to fumble with the *Set* implementation, you need to add a *get* function:

```
module Set = sig
   ...
   get : t -> elt -> elt
end
```

that will return the just asked for element. If you take the second element of the returned tuple, you have your *value* from the original *key/value* pair.